# Swift generic virtual method call leads to segfault

Tags: generics, inheritance, swift, virtual-functions

I'm new to Swift, so I might be doing something stupid. If so, great: please tell me where!

In the following code, you'll see that the class `Derived` inherits from the generic class `Base<T>`:

```
class Base<T> {
  func method(Int) -> T {
    fatalError("Subclasses must override method.")
  }
}

class Derived<T> : Base<Int> {
  override func method(input:Int) -> Int {
    return input
  }
}
```

In Swift 1.1, it isn't possible for a non-generic class to inherit from a generic one. Hence, `Derived` in this case has a dummy type variable.

If I now use these classes:

```
class Container {
  let item: Base<Int>
  init(item:Base<Int>) {
    self.item = item
  }
  func method(input:Int) -> Int {
    return item.method(input)
  }    
}
let a = Derived<Int>()
let b = Container(item:a)
let test = b.method(42)
```

the code compiles fine, but I get a segfault when `Derived<Int>.method` is invoked. Based on my debugging so far, it looks like the `self` pointer is correct within `Container.method`, but wrong once we get into `Derived<Int>.method`. Perhaps there's some stack corruption going on?

Various minor changes to this code cause it to work ok (albeit with different semantics). Can anyone explain what is going on here? I'm hesitant to suggest a compiler bug until I know a bit more about Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve definitely found a bug in the compiler or runtime – it should’t be possible to get a segfault writing code like this.  It should either run OK, or fail to compile.  You don’t even need the container class, you can reproduce the error with

```
let d: Base = Derived<Int>()
d.method(2)
```

However, even if it was a bug in the runtime that got fixed, I’d say it’s probably not a good practice to do this.  The requirement to make derived classes generic is there for a reason and using a dummy template to fudge around it probably isn’t a good idea.  For example what would it mean to declare `let d: Base = Derived<String>()`?

If `Base` has no actual implementations and is just abstract (or even if it does, and you can perhaps factor them out) you may be better off replacing the base with a protocol, perhaps with an associated type to represent T:

```
protocol P {
    // instead of T, best to call it
    // something with a meaningful name...
    typealias T

    func method(input: Int) -> T
}

class D : P {
    typealias T = Int

    func method(input: Int) -> Int {
        return input * 2
    }
}

class Container<U: P> {
    let item:  U
    init(item: U) {
        self.item = item
    }
    func method(input: Int) -> U.T {
        return item.method(input)
    }
}

let d = D()
let c = Container(item: d)
c.method(2)
```

This approach has the added benefit of allowing `D` to be a value type (i.e. a struct) if you want it to be since they can’t inherit but they can .

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. You mention that "The requirement to make derived classes generic is there for a reason". Do you know what that reason is, other than a missing feature?

Comment: I also appreciate your design recommendation for the code I posted. Unfortunately, I do need to exploit virtual method calls in the real code I'm building. A protocol with a `typealias` in it can't be treated like an abstract class and only as a type constraint. That's why I refactored my code to use inheritance, and that's where this bug showed up.

Comment: I am partly guessing since the official docs don’t say, but my explanation for why derived classes of generics need to be generic would be: Generic classes can vary in size – that is, class `A<T> { let t: T }` would be a different size depending on whether T were an `Int` (which is size of 8) or a `String` (which is size of 24).  The derived class can also vary in size because its base can, and so to account for this, needs to be generic.

Comment: Given your `Derived` class was committing to its base being an `Int`, presumably you can go for a regular protocol rather than one with an associated type, and that way you can refactor the base into a protocol?

Comment: I've gone back to seeing if I can work around with a protocol-based version again... closures might be one way. Thanks for your response. Bug report submitted to Apple :)